# Autosys Job Preference - start_times vs conditions?

Tags: autosys

if we specify start_time as well as conditions in autosys job, which get preference over another ??

For e.g. lets say start time for my job A is 06:00 AM but this job is also dependent on another job B (via conditions param) . But Job B gets becomes successful at 06:30 AM. 
So my job will start running at 06:00 AM or 06:30 AM ?

My guess is start time as well as conditions, both will be considered while running the job. So job should start at 06:30 AM. But i still want to be sure.

-Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

**Start_time:-** Job started means Activated or might be run, (if conditions are already met) at starting time.

**Conditions:-** Means job would run after given condition mate.

Example:-
Suppose job A starting time is 11:00 PM and its condition is s(B)---->B should success, B is another job that would complete at 11:30 PM. In this scenario A started at 11:00 PM but it would in active state for 30 min. than it would in running state.

Comment: Could you tell what would be the situation if it were a box instead of a job here?

Comment: In case of Box, Box would have activated at starting time but its jobs will be waiting for met applied condition. Till when applied condition would not meet no any job would come in running state.

Answer (score 1):

Your job will be in Activated state at 6:00 AM and will wait until B completes...but
consider a situation when you have another job C which is running before B. In case if C is running long and B is delayed and is not in Activated state (it is in sucessfull since run from, say, yesterday and waiting for C), you job A will also trigger as it's already 6 and B is in success (even from yesterday).
In order to avoid this, you have two ways:
1) Make B activated before A
2) Make a condition s(A, )